# How to get a quantity box to update total price

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys I'm building a simple e-commerce site from scratch rather then using Shopify and I've made all the simple front end bits however i cant seem to get the total price to update based on the quantity of products the customers picks.

So far if the customer "adds to cart" then the price and total number in cart will update by 1, but if they want to choose 2 or more it doesn't work and i was wondering how i can get it to work

HTML:

```
<button class="addcart btn btn-danger add-to-cart" type="button">Add to cart</button> //Button to add to cart 
<div class="input-group plus-minus-input"> //Quantity of product 
  <div class="input-group-button">
    <button class="button hollow circle1 btn btn-primary"
         data-field="quantity" data-quantity="minus" type="button">
      <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-minus"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
  <input class="input-group-field" name="quantity" type="number" value="0">
  <div class="input-group-button">
    <button class="button hollow circle2 btn btn-primary"
         data-field="quantity" data-quantity="plus" type="button">
      <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
<p class="cartPrice">0.00 kr</p><input id="search-submit" type="submit"> //Quantity in cart
```

Javascript:

```
//Quanity animation when the user clicks + or -
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('[data-quantity="plus"]').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     fieldName = $(this).attr('data-field');
     var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
     if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
     } else {
        $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
     }
   });
   $('[data-quantity="minus"]').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     fieldName = $(this).attr('data-field');
     var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
     if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
        $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal - 1);
     } else {
        $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
     }
   });
});

//When the user clicks add to cart this will update the total price and the quantity in the cart 
var currentItems = 0;
var cartPrice = 565.00;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".add-to-cart").click(function(){
     currentItems++;
     var totalPrice = currentItems * cartPrice;
     $(".cart-badge").text(currentItems);
     $(".cartPrice").text(totalPrice + " kr")
  });
});
```

So again I'm just trying to figure out when the user clicks on + to add more prodcuts i want the price to update to that: So if the user wants 5 products it will do 5 * 565 etc.

Thanks

Comment: Question aside, and I mean no offense by this, but if you plan on rolling your own e-commerce platform into production you should consider if it's going to be up to task. If something seemingly this trivial is tripping you up I would be concerned about the viability of the end product over something that's been established. As an exercise it's wonderful, but just be careful :)

Comment: @zfrisch I 100% agree with you but this is just an exercise for me i would never do this :) i just want to learn some javascript so i thought i would do this but i'm very stuck on this part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click "add to cart" nothing is retrieving the current quantity and so it is always static. By retrieving the value from the quantity input box your math will work correctly.

`currentItems = $("input.input-group-field[name='quantity']").val();`

```js
//Quanity animation when the user clicks + or -
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
       $('[data-quantity="plus"]').click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           fieldName = $(this).attr('data-field');
           var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
           if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
               $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
           } else {
               $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
           }
       });
       $('[data-quantity="minus"]').click(function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           fieldName = $(this).attr('data-field');
           var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
           if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
               $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal - 1);
           } else {
               $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
           }
       });
    });

//When the user clicks add to cart this will update the total price and the quantity in the cart 
    var currentItems = 0;
    var cartPrice = 565.00;
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".add-to-cart").click(function(){
           currentItems = $("input.input-group-field[name='quantity']").val();
           var totalPrice = currentItems * cartPrice;
           $(".cart-badge").text(currentItems);
           $(".cartPrice").text(totalPrice + " kr")
       });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="addcart btn btn-danger add-to-cart" type="button">Add to cart</button> //Button to add to cart 
                <div class="input-group plus-minus-input"> //Quantity of product 
                  <div class="input-group-button">
                    <button class="button hollow circle1 btn btn-primary" data-field="quantity" data-quantity="minus" type="button">-<i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                  </div>
                  <input class="input-group-field" name="quantity" type="number" value="0">
                  <div class="input-group-button">
                    <button class="button hollow circle2 btn btn-primary" data-field="quantity" data-quantity="plus" type="button">+<i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                  </div>
                </div>
<p class="cartPrice">0.00 kr</p><input id="search-submit" type="submit"> //Quantity in cart
```

Comment: This is perfect , thank you very much , helped me a lot

Comment: @RonTheOld no problem! If the answer solved your issue there's a green checkmark on the left that you can click!

Comment: I don't want to add another answer for this, because it is really similar to this one, but here's a suggestion using a function (very similar to this, good answer +1): https://jsfiddle.net/nt3p768n/10/